# Where to store reducers affecting global state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

This is my store shape:

```
export default {
    isRequesting: false,
    requestError: null,
    things: [],
    otherThings: []
}
```

When `things` and `otherThings` are being fetched from a server, `isRequesting` is changed and `requestError` could potentially be changed. Currently, I'm changing these in reducers like `reducers/thingReducer.js` and `reducers/otherThingReducer.js` for example:

```
// reducers/thingReducer.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING, LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS, LOAD_THINGS_ERROR } from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'


export function things(state = initialState.things, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS: 
            return action.things
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export function isRequesting(state = initialState.isRequesting, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING:
            return true
        case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS:
            return false
        case LOAD_THINGS_ERROR:
            return false
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export function requestError(state = initialState.requestError, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_ERROR:
            return action.error
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const thingsReducer =  {
    things,
    isRequesting,
    requestError
}

export default thingsReducer
```

As you can see I have reducers for `isRequesting` and `requestError` in my `thingReducer` and I have the same thing in `otherThingReducer` as well.

You may also see that I'm exporting each function so that I can do the following in `rootReducer.js`

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...thingReducer,
    ...otherThingReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

I've never seen this done in example code (spreading out reducers) which makes me think each reducer file, should only contain one function. I understand that this is two questions:

1. Should `isRequesting` and `requestError` live in individual reducer files (even if they are part of the global state)
2. If so, should they be spread and combined like I have done above. Even if the answer to 1) is no, can I use this spread / combine method when each reducer file actually requires multiple reducers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not spreading out reducers. `thingsReducer` is an object that contains reducers and you are spreading out that object. You can make `thingsReducer` a nested reducer if you use `combineReducers`, but I don't see a need for that:

```
const thingsReducer = combineReducers({
    things,
    isRequesting,
    requestError
})
```

As for your questions, it doesn't really matter where `isRequesting` and `requestError` are located. It's a common practice to have each reducer in its own module (check Ducks for example https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux), but that's up to you. You can also remove `thingsReducer` completely and import the reducers directly into your `rootReducer.js` like this:

```
import {things, isRequesting, requestError} from './reducers/thingReducer'
// Or if you decided to put each reducer in its own file
// import things from './reducers/thingsReducer' 
// import isRequesting from './reducers/isRequestingReducer' 
// ...

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    things,
    isRequesting,
    requestError,
    // do the same for otherThingReducer reducers
})

export default rootReducer
```

UPDATE:
To answer your question in the comments, you can do the following to simplify your code. Since you are reusing many actions, you can merge your reducers into one like this:

```
export function things(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                things: action.things,
                isRequesting: false
            }
        case LOAD_THINGS_ERROR: 
            return {
                ...state,
                requestError: action.error,
                isRequesting: false
            }
        case LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                isRequesting: true
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

If you do this, you only need to import the default `things` reducer into `rootReducer`.

Comment: Thanks, I will put them in different files to remain DRY. And then, I guess no need to spread anymore - thanks!

Comment: Actually, since  I have `LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS` etc. wouldn't it make more sense to bundle them with the `thing` reducer ? Is there a common practice of setting an independent `LOAD_SUCCESS` for any and all AJAX calls? If  so, wouldn't it be messy to dispatch `LOAD_SUCCESS` and `LOAD_PARTS_SUCCESS` ?

Comment: You can definitely reuse actions from other modules or have a shared common set of reducers. Another practice (from Ducks again) is to prefix the action name with the module/reducer name. for example `thing/LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING` and `otherThing/LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING`. I prefer not reuse actions very much and use the prefix approach to help me in debugging and tracing the flow of my app.

Comment: Okay, great - thanks. So, dispatching a `LOAD_REQUESTING` or `LOAD_ERROR` to affect the global state, and then dispatching `LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS` to affect the `things` state is fine?

Comment: Thanks, so I changed it to your latest update, but for some reason, my store is now a nested `things -> things: [...]` - I think this nesting is happening on the `LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS` and  it isn't being merged correctly

Comment: I think I know what's happening - it's nesting both `isRequesting` and `things` inside of `store.things` because that's what is being returned by the `things` reducer

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your reducer files such as your `things` reducer, you can export a constant like so:

```
export const thing = combineReducers({ things, isRequesting, requestError });
```

and then in your root reducer, you combine them the same way:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    thingReducer,
    otherThingReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

This is a matter of opinion, but I prefer to create a reducer that fits your `things`, `isRequesting` and `requestError` into one function like so:

```
// reducers/thingReducer.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { LOAD_THINGS_REQUESTING, LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS, LOAD_THINGS_ERROR } from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'

const initialThing = {
  data: {},
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false
}

const things = (
  state = initialThing,
  action
) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case LOAD_THING_REQUESTING:
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: true
        };
      case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS: 
        return {
          ...state,
          data: action.things,
          isLoading: false,
          isError: false
        };
      case LOAD_THINGS_ERROR:
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: false,
          isError: true
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default thingsReducer = combineReducers({ things, someOtherReducerFunction });
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your suggestion, I tried doing the `...state` thing initially but thought it would be considered an anti-pattern - don't see a reason why that's bad though. Have your apps been relatively complex?

Comment: It is not an anti-pattern, and is probably the most concise way of returning a new object from the reducer (Remember, we do not want to mutate state, always return a new object!). You could also accomplish this by using the assign utility function from lodash, such as `_.assign({}, state, {data: newDataHere})` or plain old Object.assign ie `Object.assign({}, state, {data: newDataHere})`

Comment: Here is a good resource for the spread operator in redux, directly from the redux docs :D 

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html